# Possible to rewrite my simple CSS code to be better

Tags: css

I am trying to learn a little bit about rewrite my CSS code. I think I am stuck on some old happits I am having. So can this CSS code be written more nice that this?

```
<style>
.result-cols ul.items li.add-item .item {
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.result-cols ul.items li.add-item {
    width: 15%;
}
.result-cols ul.items li.add-item .desc:after {
    background: none;
}
.result-cols ul.items li.add-item .desc {
    height: 30px !important;
}
.result-cols ul.items li.add-item a.button-add {
    display:none;
</style>
```

Best regards

Comment: do you use sass?

Comment: Looks like your code is starting to have specificity issues. You already use a lot of very specific selectors (some of which are not even enough and you have to resort to !important). That's something I would think about improving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your style rules start the same, with `.result-cols ul.items li.add-item`. If you won't have elements with the class `add-item` elsewhere on the page you could just remove `.result-cols ul.items li` and start your rules with `.add-item`